# IntelliJ IDEA перестал при коммите игнорировать предупреждения, связанные с особеностями работы Spring

Tags: java, spring, git, intellij-idea

При использовании возможностей Spring (`@Autowired` и т.п.) обычно появляются варнинги например:

```
Class "ClassName" is never used.
```

Которые обычно сами подавляются и при попытке коммита не всплывают.
Однако теперь они не подавляются

[image: Пример не подавленых предупреждений]

Чего хотелось бы чтобы не происходило, так как не хочу пропустить серьёзную ошибку.
Произошло это примерно после того, как у меня возникла проблема с пушем коммитов на сервер из-за переустановки операционной системы.

### UPD:

Речь про то, что IDEA при анализе кода перестала учитывать бины, объявленные с помощью аннотации @Autowired и пр. и начала сыпать Warning'ами, которые не отражают реальное положение вещей.

> ...видимо я не совсем ясно выразился. Дело в том, что spring реализует инверсию контроля, беря на себя "впрыскивание" зависимостей (с помошью @Autowired и т.п.). Однако в таком случае джаваский компилятор ругается, так как не видит явного создания и размещения объектов. Подобные варнинги раньше подавлялись самостоятельно, но перестали
> © BITniki

Comment: Вы пишите, что хотите игнорировать ворнинги...но потом пишите `Чего хотелось бы чтобы не происходило, так как не хочу пропустить серьёзную ошибку`... Я не пойму в какие ворота играть...Вам помочь их начать игнорировать или наоборот?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы **НЕ хотите** получать список сообщений об ошибках перед коммитом и хотите их игнорировать(**что я вам крайне не советую**), то выполните следующие действия:

1. Переходим в верхнее меню
2. Выбираем выпадающий список `File`
3. Выбираем пункт `Settings`
4. В левой панели раскрываем `Version Control`
5. И в нем выбираем подпункт `Commit`
6. В правой области убираем галочку с пункта `Analyze Code`

---

### По шагам

Переходим в верхнее меню
Выбираем выпадающий список `File`
**Выбираем пункт `Settings`**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В левой панели раскрываем `Version Control`**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И в нем выбираем подпункт `Commit`**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В правой области убираем галочку с пункта `Analyze Code`**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за гайд, но видимо я не совсем ясно выразился.
Дело в том, что spring реализует инверсию контроля, беря на себя "впрыскивание" зависимостей (с помошью @Autowired и т.п.). Однако в таком случае джаваский компилятор ругается, так как не видит явного создания и размещения объектов. Подобные варнинги раньше подавлялись самостоятельно, но перестали

Comment: @BITniki, понял. тут может быть проблема в том, что стоит обновить плагин Spring, также могут быть проблемы с кешом IDE и с индексацией проекта

Comment: @BITniki, попробуйте сбросить кеш и переиндексировать проект и обновить плагин отвечающий за Spring

Comment: @BITniki, еще одна возможная причина это проблемы с annotation processor

Comment: но тут нужно чуть плотнее обсуждать.
я попробую описать потом возможные решения..но эт не скоро...
если что можете в тг написать(он в профиле указан)
так опереативнее общение проходит